# What buildings do each faction like?

Tags: tropico-5

When I open up the Almanac and look at the Factions, I get to see the last half-dozen things that made the faction happy. Usually, it's pretty straightforward: "We like that constitutional amendment" or "We like that you invited the pope" or whatever. But there's one line that's fairly obtuse: "New Building", with either a + or - to show whether they liked it or hated it, but no indication of which building it is. I can make some guesses (Militarists like military buildings, right?), but I want to know: **What buildings do each faction like?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Tropico 5 Buildings**

### **Militarists**

Like - Police Station, Guard Tower, Military Fort, Barracks, Army Base, Aircraft Carrier, Nuclear Program

Dislike - None

### **Religious**

Like - Catholic Mission, Church, Cathedral

Dislike - Casino, Cabaret, Night Club, Science Lab, Space Program

### **Communists**

Like - Country House, House, Mansion, Tenement, Apartment, Modern Apartment, Clinic, Hospital

Dislike - Catholic Mission, Church, Bank

### **Capitalists**

Like - Oil Refinery, Oil Well, Lumber Mill, Textile Mill, Cannery, Steel Mill, Pharmaceutical Company, Fashion Company, Cigar Factory, Rum Distillery, Jewelry Workshop, Vehicle Factory, Chocolate Factory, Electronics Factory, Mansion, Supermarket, Bank, Customs Office, Office, Airport, Aerodome

Dislike - None

### **Environmentalists**

Like - National Park, Gardens, Waste Treatment Plant, Hang Gliding Club, Cabin, Country Hotel

Dislike - Power Plant, Nuclear Plant, Geothermal Plant, Oil Refinery, Mine, Wharf, Logging Camp, Oil Well, Factory Farm, Automated Mine, Lumber Mill, Textile Mill, Cannery, Steel Mill, Pharmaceutical Company, Fashion Company, Cigar Factory, Rum Distillery, Jewelry Workshop, Vehicle Factory, Chocolate Factory, Electronics Factory

### **Industrialists**

Like - Geothermal Plant, Oil Refinery, Oil Well, Lumber Mill, Textile Mill, Cannery, Steel Mill, Furniture Factory, Pharmaceutical Company, Fashion Company, Cigar Factory, Rum Distillery, Jewelry Workshop, Vehicle Factory, Chocolate Factory, Electronics Factory

Dislike- None

### **Nationalists**

Like - Nuclear Plant, Nuclear Program, Space Program

Dislike - Embassy

### **Globalists**

Like - Airport, Aerodome, Lighthouse, Embassy, Office

Dislike - Customs Office

[Source](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=264994893&insideModal=1)